# How can I properly escape a large block of HTML when using onClick and innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, innerhtml, quotes

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="#my_link"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('#my_link').innerHTML = ''"></a>
```

Here's the code that I want to insert into #my_link:

```
 <div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center'><form action='http://example.com' style='display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;'><p style='font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'><b>Sign In</b></p><p style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;'>It's been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Email'></input><input type='password' style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Password'></input><button type='submit' style='display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;'>Sign in</button></form></div>
```

It has a mixture of single quotes, double quotes, and carats. Whenever I try to put it into innerHTML, I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error. I've tried escaping it a bunch of different ways but I always get that error.

I have to use onClick for this, I can't use a separate script tag.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zwtr96se/

Comment: can you please add you full error.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is the full error.

Comment: ...and you want to do that _directly inline_ in your HTML code? Don't you fear it to be unreadable and unmaintainabe? Why don't you use a JS file?

Comment: try  String.raw()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ' with &quot;

```
<div id="#my_link"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('#my_link').innerHTML = '<div style=&quot;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center&quot;><form action=&quot;http://example.com&quot; style=&quot;display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;&quot;><p style=&quot;font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;&quot;><b>Sign In</b></p><p style=&quot;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;&quot;>It&quot;s been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style=&quot;display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;&quot; placeholder=&quot;Email&quot;></input><input type=&quot;password&quot; style=&quot;display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;&quot; placeholder=&quot;Password&quot;></input><button type=&quot;submit&quot; style=&quot;display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;&quot;>Sign in</button></form></div>'">Click me</a>
```

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/uLm6bwe2/

Comment: The only answer that works _and_ matches OP's requirement (not using `<script>` tags)

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. I tried &quot; but I guess I did it wrong or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach.

Assign the code to a custom attribute of hyperlink elements. Then in on click event, extract the value of that custom attribute and assign to innerHTML.
Here I attach a JSFiddle link to demonstrate above approach.

Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="#my_link"></div>

    <a href="#" custom="<div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center'><form action='http://example.com' + style='display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;'><p style='font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'><b>Sign In</b></p><p style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;'>It's been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Email'></input><input type='password' style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Password'></input><button type='submit' style='display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;'>Sign in</button></form></div>"
    onclick="document.getElementById('#my_link').innerHTML = this.getAttribute('custom');">Click Me</a>

  </body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2vckrkm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var htmlcode = "<div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center'><form action='http://example.com' style='display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;'><p style='font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'><b>Sign In</b></p><p style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;'>It's been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Email'></input><input type='password' style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Password'></input><button type='submit' style='display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;'>Sign in</button></form></div>";

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('my_link').innerHTML = unescape(htmlcode)"></a>
```

Comment: `getElementById('#my_link')` should still be `getElementById('my_link')`.

Comment: The first line would have to be in a script tag, right? I can't use script tags, only onclick.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a template string;

```
const content = ` <div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center'><form action='http://example.com' style='display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;'><p style='font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'><b>Sign In</b></p><p style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;'>It's been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Email'></input><input type='password' style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Password'></input><button type='submit' style='display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;'>Sign in</button></form></div>`
const link = document.getElementById('#my_link');
link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  link.innerHTML = link.innerHTML.length > 0 ? '' : content;
})
```

Comment: This would require a script tag, right? I can't use script tags, I can only use onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code instead

```
<div id="my_link"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="fn()">Click</a>
<script>
    function fn()
    {
        document.getElementById("my_link").innerHTML = "<div style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:100000;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); display:flex;justify-content:center;align-content:vertical;align-items:center'><form action='http://example.com' style='display: block; padding: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px #cccccc;'><p style='font-family: SharpGrotesk, Open Sans, Calibri; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'><b>Sign In</b></p><p style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 10px;'>It's been a while since you signed in.<br>For security reasons, please re-enter your credentials.</p><input style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Email'></input><input type='password' style='display:block; padding: 8px 6px 3px 18px; height: 44px; font-size:14px; width: 360px; margin-bottom: 15px;' placeholder='Password'></input><button type='submit' style='display:block;width: 360px; height: 44px; background: #0061ff; border:none; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web, Open Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;'>Sign in</button></form></div>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't use script tags, sadly.